# Converting a dataframe of 2 columns to a series of 2 columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to work on some time series data and am quite new to pandas dataframe. I have a dataframe with two columns as below:

```
+---+-----------------------+-------+--+
|   |           0           |   1   |  |
+---+-----------------------+-------+--+
| 1 | 2018-08-02 23:00:00   | 456.8 |  |
| 2 | 2018-08-02 23:01:00   | 457.9 |  |
+---+-----------------------+-------+--+
```

I am trying to convert it into a series with two columns as it is in the dataframe. How can it be done? as pd.series is converting the dataframe to a series of one column.

Comment: Could you explain what you imagine a "series with two columns" would look like?

Comment: Like below: The data type needs to be series :Index   0
 2018-08-02 23:00:00   456.8
 2018-08-02 23:01:00 457.9   Sorry I am not able to comment correctly

Answer (score 10):

There is no such thing as a pandas Series with two columns. My guess is that you want to generate a Series with column `0` as the index and column `1` as the values. You can get that by setting the index and extracting the column of interest (assuming your DataFrame is in `df`):

```
df.set_index(0)[1]
```

Comment: Or `pd.Series(df[0], df[1])` (maybe even `pd.to_datetime(df[1])` if needed)

Comment: using  like `pd.Series(df.col1, df.col2)` produces a Series with NaNs here.  `pd.Series(df.col1.values, df.col2)'  works -  just looses the Name attribute. Though pd.Series(df.col1) produces no NaN's ...  Seems buggy (pandas version 1.0.4,  PY3.7)

Comment: It is not buggy, but intended. Current dev docs clarify the behaviour: _If data is dict-like and index is None, then the keys in the data are used as the index. If the index is not None, the resulting Series is reindexed with the index values._ https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.Series.html?highlight=pandas%20series#pandas.Series

Answer (score 0):

As [stated in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51873006/converting-a-dataframe-of-2-columns-to-a-series-of-2-columns-in-python#comment111044491_51873106) using "`pd.Series(df.col1, df.col2)` produces a Series with NaNs". The reason is that the Series will be *reindexed* with the object passed as the `index` argument. [Current dev docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.Series.html?highlight=pandas%20series#pandas.Series) clarify:

> If data is dict-like and index is None, then the keys in the data are used as the index. If the index is not None, the resulting Series is reindexed with the index values.

To circumvent reindexing this can be done:

```
pd.Series(df[0].values, index=df[1])
```

Since `df[0].values` is a `pd.array`, rather than a dict-like `pd.Series`, nothing will be reindexed and `df[1]` will be set as index as-is.